# Using an instance variable's attribute as a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an index view for a Patient model that features a table:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= patient.id %></td>
    <td><%= patient.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.name if patient.user %></td>
    <td><%= patient.staff_clinician.name if patient.staff_clinician %></td>
    <td><%= patient.concerns.map(&:name).to_sentence %></td>
    <td><%= patient.genders.map(&:name).to_sentence %></td>
    <td><%= patient.races.map(&:name).to_sentence %></td>
    <td><%= patient.insurances.map(&:name).to_sentence %></td>
    <td> <%= patient.referral_requests.last.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if patient.referral_requests.last%> </td> 
   <td><%= link_to "Show", patient %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_patient_path(patient) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Remove", patient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

For this column:

```
<td> <%= patient.referral_requests.last.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if patient.referral_requests.last%> </td>
```

If a referral request exists for a patient, I want to display the datetime for created_at and have it be a hyperlink to that referral request.

If a referral request does not exist for a patient, I want to display "Create" and link to create a new referral request.

I tried nesting the entire statement in a link_to statement but can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `link_to_if`.

```
<%=
   link_to_if(patient.referral_requests.try(:last).nil?, "Create", { controller: "referral_requests", action: "new" }) do
     link_to(patient.referral_requests.last, { controller: "referral_requests", action: "show", id: patient.referral_requests.last.id})
   end
%>
```

For more detail [link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html). I hope this will help you.